# how to select a default sheet in Oracle Business Intelligence Discoverer Desktop

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence

I have added a new sheet to a report. The new sheet which I have added is the fourth sheet in the report.

When I first open the report from the database, the fourth sheet is getting executed. How to run the first sheet of the report while I open it from the database in my first attempt itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Just by going to the first sheet and clicking the save button, worked.

Next time, I am opening that report for the first time from the database.

It opened the first sheet :-)